# How to get the precision of high_resolution_clock?

Tags: c++, c++11, clock, duration, c++-chrono

C++11 defines `high_resolution_clock` and it has the member types `period` and `rep`. But I can not figure out how I can get the **precision** of that clock.

Or, if I may not get to the precision, can I somehow at least get a count in nanoseconds of the **minimum representable time duration** between ticks? probably using `period`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
void printPrec() {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::rep x = 1;
    // this is not the correct way to initialize 'period':
    //high_resolution_clock::period y = 1;

    std::cout << "The smallest period is "
              << /* what to do with 'x' or 'y' here? */
              << " nanos\n";
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `std::ratio` ?

Comment: @Yappie: partly, but how to go from there?

Comment: `std::ratio` is basically a compile time value used for compile time arithmetic. It has no instance members, only static constexpr members, so 'initializing' a ratio doesn't make any sense. You can do things like `std::ratio_less_equal<std::milli,std::high_resolution_clock::period>::value` which will be `true` if the clock's period is less than or equal to a millisecond.

Comment: Just wanted to leave a note that @bames53 has the operands swapped. Just in case anybody is not familiar with std::ratio_less_equal and wonders about the semantics (like me).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The minimum representable duration is `high_resolution_clock::period::num / high_resolution_clock::period::den` seconds. You can print it like this:

```
std::cout << (double) std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num
             / std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den;
```

Why is this? A clock's `::period` member is defined as "The tick period of the clock in seconds." It is a specialization of `std::ratio` which is a template to represent ratios at compile-time. It provides two integral constants: `num` and `den`, the numerator and denominator of a fraction, respectively.

Comment: Got it! Some day I will learn how to see where all the `ratio`s are hiding.

Answer (score 25):

I upvoted R. Martinho Fernandes's answer because I believe it offers the clearest, most straightforward answer to the question.  However I wanted to add a little code that showed a little more `<chrono>` functionality and that addressed this part of the OP's question:

> can I somehow at least get a count in nanoseconds of the minimum
>   representable time duration between ticks?

And it is impractical to put this much information into a comment.  But I otherwise regard this answer as a supportive comment to R. Martinho Fernandes's answer.

First the code, and then the explanation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

template <class Clock>
void
display_precision()
{
    typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano> NS;
    NS ns = typename Clock::duration(1);
    std::cout << ns.count() << " ns\n";
}

int main()
{
    display_precision<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>();
    display_precision<std::chrono::system_clock>();
}
```

First I created a `nanosecond` that is using a `double` as the representation (`NS`).  I used `double` just in case I needed to show fractions of a nanosecond (e.g. `0.5 ns`).

Next, every clock has a nested type named `duration`.  This is a `chrono::duration` that will have the same `std::ratio`, and thus the same `num` and `den` as pointed out in R. Martinho Fernandes's answer.  One of those `duration`s, converted to `NS` will give us how many nanoseconds in one clock tick of `Clock`.  And that value can be extracted from the `duration` with the `count()` member function.

For me this program prints out:

```
1 ns
1000 ns
```

Comment: Yes, you succeeded in raising my understanding on `chrono`. `chrono::nanoseconds` is not suitable for `NS`? Wait... I'll try it out.

Comment: Well, actually I almost had it the first time: `typename Clock::duration x{1}; cout << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(x).count() << " ns\n";` I did not succeed because I tried `x = 1` instead of `x{1}` before. This is an `explicit` constructor then.

Comment: @towi:  Correct on the explicit constructor.  This is so that one can't accidentally pass a scalar to a function taking a duration and have the duration units of that call not be explicit.

Comment: @towi:  `chrono::nanoseconds` will work for `NS` if this is an *exact* conversion between `Clock::duration` and `chrono::nanoseconds`.  For all platforms I'm aware of, this will be true.  However it is possible that `Clock::duration` might be a picosecond.  And in that case, you would get a compile-time failure when trying to convert picoseconds to the integral-based `chrono::nanoseconds`.  But using a double-based nanosecond would result in 0.001 being stored in `ns`.

Answer (score 2):

An `std::ratio` type representing the tick period of the clock, in seconds.Defined in namespace `std::chrono`

```
template<intmax_t Num, intmax_t Denom = 1 > class ratio;
```

Comment: I must admit I did not see where exactly the ratio is hiding, and how to work with it. Got it now.