# Resolution of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock doesn't correspond to measurements

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, c++-chrono

Let me ask my question by this test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using std::chrono::nanoseconds;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout 
      << "Resolution (nano) = " 
      << (double) std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::num / 
                  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::period::den * 
                  1000 * 1000 * 1000 
      << std::endl;

    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "How many nanoseconds does std::cout take?" << std::endl;
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto diff = t2-t1;
    nanoseconds ns = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(diff);

    std::cout << "std::cout takes " << ns.count() << " nanoseconds" 
              << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my machine:

> Resolution (nano) = 100
>
> How many nanoseconds does std::cout take?
>
> std::cout takes 1000200 nanoseconds

I receive either `1000200` or `1000300` or `1000400` or `1000500` or `1000600` or `2000600` as a result (= 1 or 2 microsecond). Obviously, either the resolution of `std::chrono` is **not** 100 nano-seconds **or** the way I measure the time of `std::cout` is wrong. (Why do I never receive something between 1 and 2 microseconds, for example `1500000`?)

I need a high-resolution timer in C++. The OS itself provides a high-resolution timer, because I'm able to measure things with microsecond-precision using the C# `Stopwatch` class on the same machine. So I would just need to correctly use the high-resolution timer that the OS has!

How do I fix my program to produce the expected results?

Comment: I can't answer the question, but for what it's worth, this code produces correct (nanosecond precision) results on my machine, so the problem is most likely in your library implementation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386128/how-to-get-the-precision-of-high-resolution-clock

Comment: Are you using VS2012?

Comment: Is the underlying assumption that this execution time is supposed to be constant? Doesn't the OS have scheduling processes that can affect the time on that scale? What guarantees that there is no interruption on that thread?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I'm going to guess you are using Visual Studio 2012. If not, disregard this answer. Visual Studio 2012 `typedef`'s `high_resolution_clock` to `system_clock`. Sadly, this means it has crappy precision (around 1 ms). I wrote a better high-resolution clock which uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` for use in Visual Studio 2012...

**HighResClock.h:**

```
    struct HighResClock
    {
        typedef long long                              rep;
        typedef std::nano                              period;
        typedef std::chrono::duration<rep, period>     duration;
        typedef std::chrono::time_point<HighResClock>  time_point;
        static const bool is_steady = true;

        static time_point now();
    };
```

**HighResClock.cpp:**

```
namespace
{
    const long long g_Frequency = []() -> long long
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
        return frequency.QuadPart;
    }();
}

HighResClock::time_point HighResClock::now()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER count;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&count);
    return time_point(duration(count.QuadPart * static_cast<rep>(period::den) / g_Frequency));
}
```

(I left out an assert and #ifs to see if it's being compiled on Visual Studio 2012 from the above code.)

You can use this clock anywhere and in the same way as standard clocks.

Comment: `VS2012 typedef's high_resolution_clock to system_clock` why? if I still want to use c++11 high res timer how can I force VS2012 to do that?

Comment: @javapowered They did it because they believe they have too much market share and want to turn people off of using VS. Visual Studio sucks in a number of ways, this is one of them. Above is how high_resolution_clock _should've_ been implemented in VS's standard library... It's simple too so I don't know why they just went and `typedef`'d it to `system_clock`. Maybe it just slipped through the cracks.

Comment: Interesting to know that *The VC++ 2012 implementation has been acknowledged as a bug by MS's standard library maintainer*. - (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263277/difference-between-stdsystem-clock-and-stdsteady-clock)

Comment: A bug was [reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/) for this issue, but no news on a fix yet - you could always use boost in the meantime.

Comment: Update As indicated by the last comment the bug is fixed but the fix will not be available till the next version of visual C++ "Thanks for reporting this bug. We've fixed it, and the fix will be available in the next major version of VC (i.e. after 2013)."

Comment: Is it possible to cast the result from HighResClock::now to a time_point<high_resolution_clock> in some way?

Comment: @Lallen you could either just use `high_resolution_clock::time_point` as the `time_point` for `HighResClock` which would be fine, or see [`duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast)

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2015, `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is now `typedef` to `std::chrono::steady_clock`. Straight from <chrono> `typedef steady_clock high_resolution_clock;`

Comment: @David, your multiplication `count.QuadPart * static_cast<rep>(period::den)` overflows on a system which has been running without a shutdown for a long time. After this overflow the clock starts producing wrong results.

Comment: And to add to the comment from Mark - steady_clock (and by extension high_resolution_clock) use QueryPerformanceCounter in VS2015.

Comment: Mingw64 also has this issue. Might be worth mentioning.

Comment: I can use like this:


    HighResClock::time_point startTime1 = HighResClock::now();
    HighResClock::time_point endTime1 = HighResClock::now();

    HighResClock::duration deltaTime1 = (endTime1 - startTime1);

    std::cout << "Size of count: " << sizeof(deltaTime1.count()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Delta Time 1: "  << deltaTime1.count() << std::endl;


Nanoseconds delta between end time and start time is ~(+/-)5000. This is around 5 microseconds error. I want to know if is possible to measure function call time in nanoseconds (epilogue + prologue) correctly.

Answer (score 8):

The resolution of a clock is not necessarily the same as the smallest duration that can be represented by the data type the clock uses. In this case your implementation uses a data type which can represent a duration as small as 100 nanoseconds, but the underlying clock doesn't actually have such a resolution.

---

The low resolution of Visual Studio's `high_resolution_clock` has been an issue for several years. Microsoft's C++ standard library maintainer, Stephan T. Lavavej, [has indicated](https://web.archive.org/web/20141212192132/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/) that this has been fixed in Visual Studio 2015 via the use of `QueryPerformanceCounter()`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the implementation doesn't implement the higher resolution timer?

It seems you are using Windows (you mention C#), so if you use a timer and you are indeed using Windows, you can use [QueryPerformanceFrequency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancefrequency) and [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter).

Comment: are the QPC functions also mapped to something in the std::chrono namespace?

Comment: @stefan: What's your source on that claim?

Comment: The standard just says "Objects of class high_resolution_clock represent clocks with the shortest tick period." It doesn't say in what context - the world, the system, or the implementation. IMO, this phrasing just means that no other implementation-provided clock may be more accurate. In particular, if system_clock or steady_clock were more accurate, that would be invalid. As for cppreference.com, it's a community-edited wiki and has zero normative meaning.