# Timer takes longer to reach 10.f seconds if std::cout is commented

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, conditional-statements

I have a weird problem with the value returned by my class called `Timer` (that uses `std::chrono`).

If I keep the `std::cout` commented, I have the feeling that `delta` returned by `timer.restart()` gets a very low value (it takes 3 or 4 times longer to reach **10.f**). I tried to display it, but as I said above, uncommenting the `std::cout` solves the problem.

My timer does its job well in others parts of the application, so I don't think the problem is in there.

```
void Party::gameOver(float delta)
{
    _delta += delta;
    // std::cout << _delta << std::endl; // if I uncomment this the problem is solved
    if (_delta > 10.0000f) {
        // ...
        _state = GameStatusType::Waiting;
        _delta = 0;
    }
}
```

This method is called here:

```
void Party::loop(void)
{
    Timer timer;

    while (!isFinished())
    {
        float delta = timer.restart(); // return in second

        switch (_state)
        {
        // ...
        case GameStatusType::GameOver:
            gameOver(delta);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The method "loop" is called in a thread like below:

```
void Party::run(void)
{
    _party = std::thread(&Party::loop, shared_from_this());
}
```

I don't know if this can help, but I execute this code on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. If you need further information, just ask.

Comment: What kind of granularity does your timer have? One tenth of one second, a millisecond? If you have a method on `timer` that simply returns the total time since it first started without resetting itself, have you tried using that and then calculating whether the party is finished based off the passed `delta` without taking into account your internal `_delta` variable?

Comment: Usually the restart() returns nearly between 0.001 and 0.01, and yes the timer restart itself in the restart() method. The problem occurs only if there isn't std::cout.

Comment: I'm asking, because if there's a fairly low resolution in your time, then the presence of the `std::cout` call could push the timer's measured time since reset up by one (time unit) in a rounding error. If it's otherwise lower than that, and the rounding error instead introduces an artificially low value, again due to rounding error, the `delta` will take longer to sum to 10.

Comment: With that said, that seems like a reasonable resolution to me. Would you mind humoring me and seeing what happens to the problem if you don't reset and instead pass the whole `delta` into the function on each call, and just set `_delta` to the passed in value instead of summing? If there's a relatively large error introduced by rounding, the total time will mitigate the issues called by rounding by keeping the error at 1*(average epsilon) instead of 10*Hz*(average epsilon). If the error were normally distributed that wouldn't be an issue so much, but I think that might not be the case.

Comment: well, had a mean of 0, rather than normally distributed.

Comment: I tried but I have to reset the timer, otherwise the _delta > 10 as soon as I call the function. Also, I tried to pass delta in double or in milliseconds instead of seconds, but the problem still remains, so this isn't a rounded problem I think.

Comment: hm. Well, the only other idea I have is trying to get the timing information on the loops for the commented-out std::cout, by instead appending the time to a vector, and then printing everything out when you're no longer in the loop. Using a vector should be quick enough to have much less of an effect on the timing mechanism, so you can see what kind of times you're getting there,

Comment: Additionally, you should be made aware that [high resolution clock might *not* have as high a resolution as you think it should](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299029), depending on the compiler you're using.

Comment: Are you [*sure*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47325f9746fa4243) there's no rounding error?

Comment: It looks like there is a rounded error yes but I not understand how. I'm just summing 2 double. Maybe it's an OS / compiler issue ?

Comment: I think I have found. The loop goes too fast and summing 2 double with high precision is surely bugged in windows. I'm going to check that.

Comment: Okay it's that ... All that for this. Thanks for your help I really appreciate !

Comment: It's a rounding error because the resolution of the timer is too low to correctly measure elapsed time less than either 1ms or 1us. It returns 0 when the time is too short to be measured, so if you're summing values, it'll look like there's no time elapsed at all. `cout` fixes this because i/o is very slow, and pushes it above the threshold where the time elapsed may be measured. It's not a issue with floating point precision--you're using doubles, and that gives you 15 decimal points of precision. When you're storing seconds, that's *femtosecond* precision.

Comment: The timing issue is one of the reasons why when profiling small amounts of code, people will run the loop thousands of times--execution will take too little time otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just the loop was going too fast. Just added a Sleep.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the windows console is really slow, there was many topic about this.  You may try use overlapped io to write to console to see if it's improved.